# Adding questions to the database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to add questions, options, answer to the database. I have  created table which has 5 columns
`id`, `QUESTION`, `OPTION 1`, `OPTION 2`, `OPTION 3` and `ANSWER`.

Basically, I am trying to create a quiz type game so I want to store the questions, options and its answer in my table. For that, I have created:

- a `Helperclass` which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.
- and `Questions` class which has constructor which takes 5 parameters i.e question, three options and answer and in my `mainactivity.xml`

I don't have much just a textview to display a question and three buttons to display options.

I am getting error of database stopped but I know I am very close, there is some minor mistake.

The logcat window is saying:

> ---Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    helperclassAdapter = new HelperclassAdapter(this);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelquestion);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.opt1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.opt2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.opt3);
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helperclassAdapter.helperclass.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void clickopt1(View view) {

}

public void clickopt2(View view) {

}

public void clickopt3(View view) {

}
```

**HelperclassAdapter.java**

```
public class HelperclassAdapter {
Helperclass helperclass;
Context context;

public HelperclassAdapter(Context context) {
    helperclass = new Helperclass(context);
    this.context = context;
}
static public class Helperclass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //i added the SQLiteDatabase object over here and using this object       called insert method
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DATABASE1";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 39;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "TABLE1";
    private static final String UID = "_ID";
    private static final String QUESTION = "QUESTION";
    private static final String OPT1 = "OPT1";
    private static final String OPT2 = "OPT2";
    private static final String OPT3 = "OPT3";
    private static final String ANSWER = "ANSWER";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + QUESTION + " VARCHAR(255), " + OPT1 + " VARCHAR(255), " + OPT2 + " VARCHAR(255), " + OPT3 + " VARCHAR(255), " + ANSWER + " VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;


    public Helperclass(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        Toast.makeText(context, "constructor called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        try {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            addquestions();
            Toast.makeText(context, "oncreate called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "onupgrade called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public void addquestions() {
        Questions q1 = new Questions("what is your hobby?", "singing", "dancing", "reading", "sining");
        this.addingeachquestions(q1);
        Questions q2 = new Questions("how are you?", "fine", "good", "sad", "good");
        this.addingeachquestions(q2);
        Questions q3 = new Questions("whats your name?", "sam", "jhon", "alice", "sam");
        this.addingeachquestions(q3);
        Toast.makeText(context, "addquestion method called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   //BEFORE
    private void addingeachquestions(Questions question) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Helperclass.QUESTION, question.getQUESTION());
        values.put(Helperclass.OPT1, question.getOPTA());
        values.put(Helperclass.OPT2, question.getOPTB());
        values.put(Helperclass.OPT3, question.getOPTC());
        values.put(Helperclass.ANSWER, question.getANSWER());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(Helperclass.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Toast.makeText(context, "questions added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
     //AFTER
    private void addingeachquestions(Questions question) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Helperclass.QUESTION, question.getQUESTION());
        values.put(Helperclass.OPT1, question.getOPTA());
        values.put(Helperclass.OPT2, question.getOPTB());
        values.put(Helperclass.OPT3, question.getOPTC());
        values.put(Helperclass.ANSWER, question.getANSWER());
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(Helperclass.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Toast.makeText(context, "questions added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**Questions.java**

```
public Questions() {
    Question = "";
    Opt1 = "";
    Opt2 = "";
    Opt3 = "";
    Answer = "";
}

public Questions(String qUESTION, String oPT1, String oPT2, String oPT3,
                 String aNSWER) {
    Question = qUESTION;
    Opt1 = oPT1;
    Opt2 = oPT2;
    Opt3 = oPT3;

    Answer = aNSWER;
}

public String getQUESTION() {
    return Question;
}

public String getOPTA() {
    return Opt1;
}

public String getOPTB() {
    return Opt2;
}

public String getOPTC() {
    return Opt3;
}

public String getANSWER() {
    return Answer;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add logcat messages?

Comment: If you are really a beginner, you should check naming conventions in Java. It's kinda hard to get what is a class or a variable in your code. You can find the ones from Google [there](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

Comment: i have put the logcat window message in my edited question above!!

Comment: it is saying java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively.

Answer (score -1):

1. I would advice you using ContentProvider to uset the database. If you begginer it looks scary but you must learn it!

Content provider is a way for you and other apps (if you choose to) to access your database in teh right way.

[ContentProvider documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

2. I think the hp variable isnt intalized?

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
       try {
           sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

   // hp isnt intallized?

           hp.addquestions();

           Toast.makeText(context, "oncreate called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
   ```

Read my comments, once again read about contentProvider! its really important and not just for creating your own database but for you to work with other databases. (like getting images from the gallery)

```html
    private void addingeachquestions(Questions question) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Helperclass.QUESTION, question.getQUESTION());
        values.put(Helperclass.OPT1, question.getOPTA());
        values.put(Helperclass.OPT2, question.getOPTB());
        values.put(Helperclass.OPT3, question.getOPTC());
        values.put(Helperclass.ANSWER, question.getANSWER());

//getWritableDatabase calls the onCreate() methos and the onCreate() method calls             addquestions(); which calls getWriteableDatabase. this is recrusive call, a method that makes infinity loop that crush your app.
You should add the questions OUTSIDE the Helperclass.

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(Helperclass.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Toast.makeText(context, "questions added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: yes it has been initalized i have edited my code above please have a look.

Comment: the logcat window is saying---java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively.

Comment: check my comments in your code (The bottum part of the answer)

Comment: //getWritableDatabase calls the onCreate() methos and the onCreate() method calls             addquestions(); which calls getWriteableDatabase. this is recrusive call, a method that makes infinity loop that crush your app.
You should add the questions OUTSIDE the Helperclass.

Comment: ok so now instead of adding  addingeachquestions() Method outside Helperclass class which was calling  getWritableDatabase() method.  i removed getWritableDatabase() from the  addingeachquestions() Method itself and created  object of SQLiteDatabase inside the Helperclass and using that object called the insert method. i have edited my code please help it is giving null pointer exception in MainActivity.java  in oncreate method at this lineSQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=helperclass.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: sqLiteDatabase isnt initialized. (Ita null)